# Increment a Formatted Code in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a code format for every category selected from the drop down menu. 
Say for Category A, the code to be retrieved in the textbox is "A - 1001" and for Category B, "B - 2003". My problem is that I can't increment the code into "A - 1002" for category A, for example because it's already read as string.

How can I retrieve a formatted code from the database which will increment its value?

Here's my code for the selection of category and for the retrieval of the code:

```
  Category:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelected (selectTag) {
        var selIndexes = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < selectTag.options.length; i++) {
            var optionTag = selectTag.options[i];
            if (optionTag.selected) {
                if (selIndexes.length > 0)
                    selIndexes += ", ";
                selIndexes = optionTag.value;
            }
        }

        var info = document.getElementById ("viocode");
        if (selIndexes.length > 0) {
            viocode.innerHTML = selIndexes;
        }
        else {
            info.innerHTML = "There is no selected option";
        }
    }

  </script>
                <select option="single"  name= "viocat" id="viocat" onchange="GetSelected (this);" class = "form-control">
    <option>Choose category ...</option>
    <option value="

 <?php
 $con = ...

 $sql = "SELECTcategory, MAX(code) AS highest_id FROM tbl_name where category = 1";

 $result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $i = $row['highest_id'];
    $i++;
    echo "A - " .$i;
    $cat = 1;
 }  

 ?>">DlR</option>

 <option value=" 
 <?php
 $con =  ...

 $sql = "SELECT category, MAX(code) AS highest_id FROM tbl_name where category = 2";

 $result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $i = $row['highest_id'];
    $i++;
    echo "B - " .$i;
    $cat = 2;
  }  

 ?>">B</option>

 <option value="
 <?php
 $con = ...

$sql = "SELECT category, MAX(code) AS highest_id FROM tbl_name where category = 3";

$result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $i = $row['highest_id'];
    $i++;
    echo "C - " .$i;
    $cat = 3;
}  

?>">C</option>
</select>
```

And here's the codes for the textbox where the formatted code is to be displayed:

```
 Violation Code:
 <strong><text type= "text" id="viocode"  name="viocode" />
```

Comment: Do you need to parse to int a string?

Comment: Hi Sir thanks for the response! :) If the value added to the database is "A - 1001" for ex., would it be possible Sir to parse it to int and increment its value? I'm really having trouble in doing it Sir. I'm thinking of just separating " A - " to "1001" but I don't know how to.. I mean in every selection it would retrieve two value at the same textbox and then save the " A - " as category "A" in the field category and "1001" in the field "code" in my db. @Hexadect

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you need to increment a number ($i), from  $row['highest_id'].

The extra line will try to parse the $row['highest_id'] as an int, then your code uses it, and the last line of the while loop increments $i with 1.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {  
        $i = intval($row['highest_id']);
        //$i = $row['highest_id'];
        echo "A - " .$i;
        $cat = 1;
        $i++;
     }
```

Comment: Yes Sir. My problem is that when I saved it in the database and add a new record the code does not increment because it's already read as string as "A - 1001" for ex. @Gyula

Comment: I've already tried it Sir but it's only giving me a NULL value in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your variable to integer.

Instead of using `$row['highest_id']`
     use: `$i = intval($row['highest_id'];`